# Excel 2013 - How to copy data from one sheet to another based on formatting

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet with values, and I want to automatically copy only the values that are highlighted (formatted with background color) to another sheet.
I don't mind using a macro, or if possible a function in the second sheet cells.

I've tried to put a few suggestions together and created a function to return the cell color and this following macro to filter by the color value:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        '~~> Filter, offset(to exclude headers) and set the source location
        With .Range("J2:J" & lRow)
             .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="6"
             Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        End With

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    '~~> Destination Sheet
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    With ws2
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            lRow = 1
        End If

        copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)
    End With
End Sub

Function InteriorColor(CellColor As Range)
    InteriorColor = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

But, I need to copy from several sheets to a single sheet, and the macro states that the source sheet is constant... I wouldn't want to create a macro for each separate sheet.

In addition, each time I will run the macro, it will copy the highlighted lines which were already copied before thus creating duplicates in the destination sheet.

I've looked into many SO posts regarding this issue but couldn't find anything that suits my needs.

Can anyone suggest how to change this code or have a new optimized one?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I think this should be separated into two problems:

### Import from different worksheets

If you want to import from different sheets, you should write your function to accept a sheet as a parameter.

```
Sub Sample(ws As Excel.Worksheet)
```

Then you need to remove both the lines `Dim ws As Worksheet` and `Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")`, or you will get an error or unexpected behavior.

Then you need another function that loops through all the worksheets and calls your *Sample(Worksheet)* procedure.

```
Sub SampleCaller()
  dim e, ws as Excel.Worksheet
  For Each e in ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Set ws = e
    Call Sample(ws)
  Next e
  Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

### Find already existing rows in destination worksheet

You are already using the [**Range.Find** method (Link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx).
You can use it to find already existing elements in your destination worksheet.
Before Calling `copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)` you should use Range.Find to determine whether you need to copy this value.

Maybe you should create another topic for this second issue, or use the search function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!
It seems like a good idea to loop through the sheets. I'll use that loop and search for an answer to the second issue or create a new topic.
Much obliged!

Comment: Hi, I've added this code and the issue I see now is that in the destination sheet, the cells are copied with a -1 offset, overwriting the last line each iteration, meaning - if I iterate through 5 sheets, the last 5 lines in the destination sheet are overwritten...
How can I avoid that from happening?
Thanks!